# Simple encryption based on MD5

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography

I made a Python 3(.4.2) program that only adds classes and is meant to be imported. It allows the creation of files that store usernames and hashed passwords. It uses [salting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) as well. It also can easily check if any given string is the original password (through the `User.check()` attribute of the `User` class.)

```
"""A simple encryption module"""

__version__ = "1.0.0"

__all__ = ["generate_salt", "User", "Database"]

import hashlib
import random

_POSSIBLE_CHARS = ("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                   "!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~")


def generate_salt(length=64):
    """Returns a salt of length length.
    This is from all lowercase printable not-whitespace characters.
    """
    return "".join((random.choice(_POSSIBLE_CHARS) for n in range(length)))


class User:
    """Stores the username/password for one user
    and the logic to write it to a file.
    """
    def __init__(self, password=None, username=None, file=None,
                 case_sensitive=None, salt=None):
        self.salt = generate_salt() if salt is None else salt
        if password is not None and not isinstance(password,
                                                   hashlib._hashlib.HASH):
            try:
                password = (password + self.salt).encode()
            except AttributeError:
                password = password + self.salt.encode()
            self.password = hashlib.md5(password)
            del password  # Just in case
            self.password_digest = str(self.password.digest())[2:-1]
        elif isinstance(password, hashlib._hashlib.HASH):
            self.password = password
            self.password_digest = str(self.password.digest())[2:-1]
        else:
            self.password = None
            self.password_digest = None
        if username is not None:
            self.username = username if case_sensitive else username.lower()
        else:
            self.username = None
        self._previous_username = ""
        self._pending_write = True
        if file is not None:
            with open(file, "a") as f:
                f.write("")  # To make sure it's a valid file
        self.file = file  # Can be None
        self.case_sensitive = False if case_sensitive is None else not \
                              not case_sensitive

    @classmethod
    def get_from_file(cls, file, username, case_sensitive=None):
        """Gets username and password from provided file. Returns None."""
        case_sensitive = False if case_sensitive is None else not not \
                         case_sensitive
        i = 0
        salt = False
        with open(file) as f:
            lines = "".join(f.readlines()).split("\n")
        for line in lines:
            i += 1
            if not not salt:
                password = hashlib.md5(line.encode())
                break
            if i:
                if line[:-64] == username:
                    salt = a[-64:]
        return cls(password, username, file, case_sensitive, salt)

    def set_file(self, new_file):
        """Sets the file. Returns None."""
        with open(new_file, "a") as f:
            f.write("")
        self.file = new_file

    def set_username(self, new_username):
        """Sets username. Returns None"""
        if not self._pending_write:
            self.previous_username = self.username
            self.username = new_username
        else:
            raise Exception("Pending write to file")

    def set_password(self, new_password):
        """Sets password. Returns None"""
        try:
            new_password = new_password.encode()
        except AttributeError:
            password = password + self.salt.encode()
        self.password = hashlib.md5(new_password)
        del new_password
        self.password_digest = str(self.password.digest())[2:-1]

    def set_case_sensitivity(self, new_case_sensitivity):
        """Sets case-sensitivity. Returns None"""
        self.case_sensitive = not not new_case_sensitivity

    def write_to_file(self):
        """Updates file with password.
        If username exsists in file, updates passwords.
        else, creates 2 new lines in the format:
        [username][salt]
        [password]
        """
        if None in (self.file, self.password, self.username):
            raise ValueError("Must have username, password and file")
        if self.username == "":
            raise ValueError('Username cannot be "" (blank)')
        with open(self.file) as f:
            f.seek(0, 0)
            lines = "".join(f.readlines()).split("\n")
        lines = ["", ""] if lines == [""] else lines
        passwords = lines[1::2]
        usernames = lines[::2]
        if not self.case_sensitive:
            usernames = [username.lower() for username in usernames]
            lines = [lines[line].lower() if not line % 2 else lines[line] for line in range(len(lines))]
        for n in range(len(usernames)):
            if usernames[n][:-64] == self._previous_username:
                usernames[n] = self.username + self.salt
                passwords[n] = self.password_digest
                break
        new_lines = []
        for n in range(len(usernames)):
            new_lines.append(usernames[n])
            new_lines.append(passwords[n])
        with open(self.file, "w") as f:
            f.write("\n".join(new_lines))

    def check(self, password):
        """Checks if a string is the original encoded password."""
        try:
            password = (password + self.salt).encode()
        except AttributeError:
            password = password + self.salt.encode()
        return str(hashlib.md5(password).digest())[2:-1] == self.password_digest


class Database:
    """A database is a collection of user classes.
    The union of these users is the file, a "database\""""
    def __init__(self, file, case_sensitive=None):
        self.case_sensitive = False if case_sensitive is None else not not \
                              case_sensitive
        self.file = file
        self.users = {}
        with open(file) as f:
            lines = "".join(f.readlines()).split("\n")
        if lines == [""]:
            return
        for n in range(0, len(lines), 2):
            self.users[lines[n][:-64]] = [hashlib.md5(lines[n + 1].encode()), lines[n][-64:]]
        for user in self.users:
            self.users[user] = User(self.users[user][0], user, file,
                                    case_sensitive, self.users[user][1])

    def get_user(self, username, default=None):
        """Returns a User() class assigned to a username.
        Returns default otherwise.
        """
        return self.users.get(username, default)

    def has_user(self, username):
        """Returns the exsistence of a username in the database."""
        return True if username in self.users else False

    def add_user(self, username, password, salt=None):
        """Adds a user, returns None.
        Parameter salt is only used if password given is a hash"""
        username = username.lower() if not self.case_sensitive else username
        if self.has_user(username):
            raise ValueError("User already exists.")
        self.users[username] = User(password, username, self.file,
                                    self.case_sensitive, salt)
        self.get_user(username).write_to_file()

    def remove_user(self, username):
        """Removes a user, their salt and their password from the dateabase file."""
        username = username.lower() if not self.case_sensitive else username
        user = self.get_user(username)
        if user is None:
            raise ValueError("User does not exsist.")
        with open(self.file) as f:

            lines = "".join(f.readlines()).split("\n")
        for n in range(0, len(lines), 2):
            if lines[n] == username:
                break
        new_lines = lines[:n] + lines[:n + 2]
        with open(self.file, "w") as f:
            f.seek(0, 0)
            f.write(new_lines)

    def clear(self):
        """Clears the database of users and blanks out its folder."""
        self.users = {}
        with open(self.file, "w") as f:
            return

    def check_password(self, username, password):
        """Returns True if the password is that of the username, else False"""
        username = username.lower() if not self.case_sensitive else username
        if self.has_user(username):
            return self.get_user(username).check(password)
        return False
```

I would like some feedback on how effective this code is, especially in the file I/O, as this is my first time working with files.

A test case of using the `Database()` class:

```
>>> db = Database("db.txt", True)
>>> db.clear()
>>> db.add_user("Reticality", "notMyPass")
>>> db.check_password("reticality", "123")
False
>>> db.check_password("reticality", "notMyPass")
False
>>> db.check_password("Reticality", "notMyPass")
True
>>> new_db = Database("new_db.txt")
>>> new_db.clear()
>>> db.add_user("retIcAlItY", "pass")
>>> db.check_password("Reticality", "pass")
True
>>> db.check_password("retIcAlItY", "pass")
True
```

The usernames / passwords are stored in a file, so you could restart it and not need to add the users every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Style**

Your code looks good and is properly documented. Using various tools to check it, here is what we have.

With `pep8` :

```
E127 continuation line over-indented for visual indent
E126 continuation line over-indented for hanging indent
E501 line too long
```

So nothing very worrying.

With `pylint` :

```
C:120, 0: Line too long (104/80) (line-too-long)
C:155, 0: Line too long (93/80) (line-too-long)
C:181, 0: Line too long (84/80) (line-too-long)
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
F:  5, 0: Unable to import 'hashlib' (invalid syntax (<string>, line 6)) (import-error)
R: 19, 0: Too many instance attributes (9/7) (too-many-instance-attributes)
R: 23, 4: Too many arguments (6/5) (too-many-arguments)
W: 27,51: Access to a protected member _hashlib of a client class (protected-access)
W: 35,34: Access to a protected member _hashlib of a client class (protected-access)
C: 48,36: Invalid variable name "f" (invalid-name)
C: 61,27: Invalid variable name "f" (invalid-name)
E: 70,27: Undefined variable 'a' (undefined-variable)
C: 75,36: Invalid variable name "f" (invalid-name)
E: 92,23: Using variable 'password' before assignment (used-before-assignment)
C:112,32: Invalid variable name "f" (invalid-name)
C:121,12: Invalid variable name "n" (invalid-name)
C:127,12: Invalid variable name "n" (invalid-name)
C:130,37: Invalid variable name "f" (invalid-name)
W: 82,12: Attribute 'previous_username' defined outside __init__ (attribute-defined-outside-init)
C:150,27: Invalid variable name "f" (invalid-name)
C:154,12: Invalid variable name "n" (invalid-name)
C:186,32: Invalid variable name "f" (invalid-name)
C:189,12: Invalid variable name "n" (invalid-name)
W:192,27: Using possibly undefined loop variable 'n' (undefined-loop-variable)
W:192,39: Using possibly undefined loop variable 'n' (undefined-loop-variable)
C:193,37: Invalid variable name "f" (invalid-name)
C:200,37: Invalid variable name "f" (invalid-name)
W:200,37: Unused variable 'f' (unused-variable)
```

Errors `Undefined variable` are definitly something you should look at because there would lead to severe errors.

Warnings `Unused variable` are a good hint that something is probably not quite what you wanted to do.

And `pyflakes` leads to pretty similar results :

```
crypto.py:35: undefined name 'password'
crypto.py:36: undefined name 'password'
crypto.py:70: undefined name 'a'
crypto.py:92: undefined name 'password'
crypto.py:92: local variable 'password' is assigned to but never used
crypto.py:200: local variable 'f' is assigned to but never used
```

Now, there is quite a lot of code and I have a limited times so I'll just point out other things that could easily be improved.

**Basic logic**

By reorganising the code in :

```
    if password is not None and not isinstance(password,
                                               hashlib._hashlib.HASH):
        try:
            password = (password + self.salt).encode()
        except AttributeError:
            password = password + self.salt.encode()
        self.password = hashlib.md5(password)
        del password  # Just in case
        self.password_digest = str(self.password.digest())[2:-1]
    elif isinstance(password, hashlib._hashlib.HASH):
        self.password = password
        self.password_digest = str(self.password.digest())[2:-1]
    else:
        self.password = None
        self.password_digest = None
```

You can make it much clearer. You could handle the `None` case first.

```
    if password is None:
        self.password = None
        self.password_digest = None
    elif isinstance(password, hashlib._hashlib.HASH):
        self.password = password
        self.password_digest = str(self.password.digest())[2:-1]
    else:
        try:
            password = (password + self.salt).encode()
        except AttributeError:
            password = password + self.salt.encode()
        self.password = hashlib.md5(password)
        del password  # Just in case
        self.password_digest = str(self.password.digest())[2:-1]
```

**Don't repeat yourself**

In the code above, a part of the logic is duplicated.

```
    if password is None:
        self.password_digest = None
    else:
        if not isinstance(password, hashlib._hashlib.HASH):
            try:
                password = (password + self.salt).encode()
            except AttributeError:
                password = password + self.salt.encode()
            password = hashlib.md5(password)
        self.password_digest = str(password.digest())[2:-1]
    self.password = password
```

Similarly, you can rewrite :

```
    if username is not None:
        self.username = username if case_sensitive else username.lower()
    else:
        self.username = None
```

by inversing conditions and replacing `None` by `username` when it is the same:

```
    if username is None:
        self.username = None
    else:
        self.username = username if case_sensitive else username.lower()
```

Then, this is nothing but

```
    self.username = username if username is None or case_sensitive else username.lower()
```

**Counting - the pythonic way**

You are trying to count iterations in :

```
    i = 0
    for line in lines:
        i += 1
        blabla
```

A builtin called [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) exists just for this usage. You could write your code :

```
    for i, line in enumerate(lines, start=1):
        blabla
```

**Pointless checks**

In the same loop, you are checking `if i`. This condition will always be true as far as I can tell.

This leads me to my last point :

**Try to write unit tests and check code coverage**

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm ready to learn if I said something wrong.